# MySQl Query with loops without creating as procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can we execute this loop without creating them as a procedure or function, in the direct query window.

```
DELIMITER $$;
BEGIN
    DECLARE counts INT;
    SET counts:=0;
    WHILE counts < 10 DO
        Select counts;
        SET counts = counts + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried, it does not execute and resulted with below exception :

Unknown system variable 'counts'

Expectation :

while developing need to do certain loops as per logic defined. to ensure it is working without error. need to test the logic without creating as a procedure.

we have option in Postgres to execute the procedure statement by DO.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
counts INT default 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE counts < 10 loop
        raise notice 'count : %' , counts;
        counts:= counts + 1;
    END loop;
END
$$;
```

Result :

NOTICE:  count : 0
NOTICE:  count : 1
NOTICE:  count : 2
NOTICE:  count : 3
NOTICE:  count : 4
NOTICE:  count : 5
NOTICE:  count : 6
NOTICE:  count : 7
NOTICE:  count : 8
NOTICE:  count : 9
DO

Query returned successfully in 210 msec.

[postgres result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJiM.png)

Comment: You loose `CREATE PROCEDURE`...

Comment: I need to know whether it can be executed without creating as a procedure @Akina

Comment: MySQL does not support anonymous codeblocks.

Comment: 'MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html , Is poorly worded but in effect ONLY supports in stored programs.